# AngularJS Http-Service get no Data

Tags: angularjs, json, http, azure

I work with angularJs and Ionic and I want to get Data from azure.

The link to the table 'Winzer' is:
https://winetastic.azurewebsites.net/tables/Winzer?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0

When I open that link I get:

```
[{"id":"b15f5cf0-e576-4b6a-8fec-9e22a9e52630","createdAt":"2017-01-31T22:49:01.016Z","updatedAt":"2017-02-02T07:13:59.587Z","version":"AAAAAAAAHM4=","deleted":false,"Name":"Winzer 1","Streetname":"Straße 1","Address":"Adresse","Phone":null,"Mail":null,"URL":null,"Region":"Region ","Fax":null}]
```

I want to show the attribute 'Name' in an 'ion-list'

my controller looks like this:

```
.controller('winzerCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', 'WineService', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, WineService) { 
$http.get("https://winetastic.azurewebsites.net/tables/Winzer?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0").then(function (response) { $scope.winzerList = response.data.records; });}])
```

and my html site looks like this:

```
<ion-list id="winzer-list9" class="manual-list-fullwidth">
  <ion-item ng-repeat="winzer in winzerList | filter:test "class="item-icon-left" id="winzer-list-item33" ui-sref="winetastic.winzerDetails">
    <i class="icon ion-android-contact"></i>{{winzer.Name}}</ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

When I run the Project, i don't get an error but no data were shown in the list.
Whats wrong?

Comment: Doesn't `response.data` hold data you want to assing to winzerList and `response.data.records` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kasper Ziemianek said, you should replace

```
$scope.winzerList = response.data.records;
```

with

```
$scope.winzerList = response.data;
```